# The type of the argument object [type] is not primitive

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I'm trying to create a simple Guestbook web service using ASP.NET WebServices.

When trying to serialize a list of objects, I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The type of the argument object 'GuestBookService.GuestBookEntry' is not primitive.
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Could you please post some of the code around the line that throws this error? It's hard to diagnose in isolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is GuestBookEntry marked as serializable? 
http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/08/26/serialization.html

Answer (score 2):

If GuestBookService is a subclass and the attribute holding it is of its superclass' type, then you have to give the Serializer extra types like this:

```
Type[] extraTypes = {typeof(GuestBookService)};
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataContainerClass),extraTypes);
```

Comment: For some reason even with `XMLInclude` and `KnownType` in the parent class I still had to do this to clear an error when trying to communicate with a WCF service from an android app.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact error, but in my case the solution was different.
My mistake was that I created a web method that returned a base class type, and tried to return derived classes.

```
public BaseClass MyMethod() { /*...*/ }
```

I'd try to return BaseClassDerivativeA, BaseClassDerivativeB etc. The derived classes added fields of their own to the base class's fields.
I Noticed polymorphism in this sense seems to be [not supported](http://forums.asp.net/post/4583264.aspx).

I have generalized my derivative classes to a single class and thus removed this kind of polymorphism in the return type. This fixed my error.